# is there a way to not stop script if errors found?

Tags: php

i have a php script which sometimes makes some light errors that are not important, but the script stops executing next lines. i want some `ini_set` or something to make it executes all the script even if there is warning or errors.

note: i can't fix those errors.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you fix those errors? Errors are important in PHP, that's why your program is not completing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are fatal errors, the script will stop no matter what and you can do nothing about it. You see there is nothing like "Resume on error" thing like that is in vb. You can suppress the errors though with @ character.

Comment: Thanks, those currently are just warnings, is the warning stops the script?

Comment: There must be some other fatal error, you should put this on top of your script:

ini_set("display_errors", true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the "unimportant" code in a try/catch block: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

You probably want to understand why the errors are happening first, though. I'm concerned about the fact that you say the errors aren't important and that you can't fix them.

Comment: That won't really catch the E_WARNINGs he's seeing, though.